# Install libraries in Google Coral TPU

Tags: tpu, google-coral

I tried to install the following libraries without success on Google Coral TPU. These libraries I want to cooperate with tensorflow lite:

```
pandas 
numpy 
scikit-learn 
scikit-image 
click tqdm
```

In Google Coral TPU, in order to work with tensorflow lite, and I am getting these errors:

```
File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 422, in generate_config_h
          moredefs, ignored = c6wfs --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel Cython>=0.29.13 "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system=='AIX'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I am searching all day to find something on google without any success. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` should already be installed, right?
Any other libraries should be install-able using apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-sklearn python3-skimage python3-pandas
$ sudo pip3 install tqdm
```

Comment: Why would you install the python libraries through apt (with its `python3-` version) and not directly through `pip3`? OP did not even specify how he was trying to install the libraries. (Genuine question!)